# Trouble printing out toString() jgetting null

Tags: java

I have a program to print the students and their results from an exam and more.
but I have a problem.
The printing should be:

> Anna Andersson anna@mmail.com UPPGIFTER: 4 5 6 2 6 8 9 3 SUMMA: 43
> BETYG: VG GODKÄND: true
>
> Bengt Bengtsson bengt@umu.se UPPGIFTER: 6 0 0 1 4 6 6 1 SUMMA: 24 BETYG: G GODKÄND: true
>
> Cecilia Carlsson cilla@ccc.se UPPGIFTER: 2 3 4 0 0 0 1 3 SUMMA: 13 BETYG: U GODKÄND:
> false

But the printing is:

> null null null UPPGIFTER: 4 5 6 2 6 8 9 3 SUMMA: 43 BETYG: VG GODKÄND:
> true
>
> Anna Andersson anna@mmail.com UPPGIFTER: 6 0 0 1 4 6 6 1 SUMMA:
> 24 BETYG: G GODKÄND: true
>
> Bengt Bengtsson bengt@umu.se UPPGIFTER: 2 3 4 0 0 0 1 3 SUMMA: 13 BETYG: U
> GODKÄND: false

I get NULL NULL NULL where Anna should be and Cecilia is missing.

This is a class that implements an interface.

```
public class Grade implements GradeInterface {

    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String email;
    String TrueFalse;
    String utskrift;
    String betyget;
    int sum = 0;
    boolean TF;
    String formatedString;
    
    @Override
    public void setUp(StudentInterface student, List<Integer> sumsForPartialAssignment, AssignmentInterface assignment) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        firstName = student.getFirstName();
        lastName = student.getLastName();
        email = student.getEmail();

    
        
        for (int i = 0; i < sumsForPartialAssignment.size(); i++) {
            sum += sumsForPartialAssignment.get(i);
        }
        betyget = assignment.getGrade(sum);

        TrueFalse = assignment.getGrade(sum);
        TF = TrueFalse.equals(GradesConstants.pass) || TrueFalse.equals(GradesConstants.passWithDistinction);

        formatedString = sumsForPartialAssignment.toString().replace(",", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
        
       System.out.println(toString());

    }

    @Override
    public String getGrade() {

        return TrueFalse;
        
    }

    @Override
    public int getSum() {
        return sum;

        }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPassed() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        utskrift = (firstName + " " + lastName + " " + email + " " + "UPPGIFTER: " + formatedString + " " +  "SUMMA: " + sum + " " + "BETYG: " + betyget + " " + "GODKÄND: " + TF);
        return utskrift;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have another class that implements the textfile from were the students info is read from. Can it be some trouble with my for loop in that class?

Comment: Yes, the problem is in another class. Can you show how you set the student's first/last names and its email?

Comment: @hjem it seems your 'StudentInterface student' is not set up correctly. Can you show more of your code?

Comment: Have you used a debugger and see what the values are in `setUp` when it's called? That should help direct you to figuring out the issue. As @aniri mentioned, it sounds like the issue is with setting up and populating `StudentInterface student`